# cin / cout being skipped

Tags: c++, cout, cin

I've been writing a sample program to compare runtimes of some algorithms, and this one has been causing me some trouble. For some reason, cin / cout is randomly skipped at various parts throughout the program, and I'm not entirely certain as to why. Here's the code, with the offending lines commented. find_element has been commented out for debugging, but doesn't work either. Any advice would be great!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void sort_vect( vector< int >& );
// int find_element( vector< int > );
void print_vect( vector< int > );

int main()
{
    vector< int > int_vect;
    int input;
    int result;

    char garbage;

    cout << "Enter a number into the vector (Q to quit) > ";

    while(cin >> input && input != 'Q' && input != 'q')
    {
        int_vect.push_back(input);
        cout << "> ";
    }

    // The following doesn't help
    // cin >> garbage;
    // cout << "Garbage : " << garbage << endl;

    if (int_vect.size() == 0)
    {
        cout << "Vector empty" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    sort_vect(int_vect);
    print_vect(int_vect);

    cout << "What value do you want > ";
    cin >> input;   

    cout << "Result : " << int_vect[input-1] << endl;

    return 0;
} // main()

void sort_vect( vector< int >& int_vect)
{
    vector< int >::iterator vect_iterator;
    vector< int >::iterator temp_iterator;

    int temp_store = NULL;

    for(vect_iterator = int_vect.begin(); vect_iterator != int_vect.end(); vect_iterator++)
    {
        for (temp_iterator = vect_iterator; temp_iterator != int_vect.begin(); temp_iterator--)
        {
            while(*temp_iterator < *(temp_iterator-1))
            {
                temp_store = *temp_iterator;
                *temp_iterator = *(temp_iterator-1);
                *(temp_iterator-1) = temp_store;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "Vector sorted." << endl << endl;
}

// int find_element( vector< int > int_vect)
// {
//  int input;
//  char garbage;
//  
//  cout << "Enter value to be returned (5 = 5th smallest) > ";
//  cin >> input;
//  cout << "Value for input : " << input << endl;
//      
//  return int_vect[input-1];
// }

void print_vect( vector< int > int_vect )
{
    vector< int >::iterator vect_iterator = int_vect.begin();

    while(vect_iterator != int_vect.end())
    {
        cout << *vect_iterator << endl;
        vect_iterator++;
    }
} // print_vect()
```

As per request, the output (Note : input is wrong as I forgot to properly use the input as an index, but that's not the problem at the moment) :

```
Enter a number into the vector (Q to quit) > 1
> 2
> 4
> 6
> 5
> 3
> 4
> q
Vector sorted.

1
2
3
4
4
5
6
What value do you want > Result : 4
```

Comment: Could you include the output from an actual session, showing `cin` / `cout` being randomly skipped?

Comment: I don't know about skipped but there an obvious problem in that you read an integer `cin >> input` and then you try to compare it with a character `input != 'Q' && input != 'q'`. That's not going to work. If you want to allow input to be an integer or 'Q' to quit then you have to read a string first, check if it's "Q" or "q" and then convert the string to an integer if it is not. A bit more complicated than the code you have.

Comment: `input` is an `int`, so trying to input a `'Q'` will never work, and it'll put the stream into a bad state that needs to be explicitly cleared before it'll work normally again.

Comment: Added the output, and thank you for the correction on the input comparison! Would that potentially cause any problems of this nature? Michael : Thanks, that was it! Called cin.clear() and cin.ignore() after the loop and it worked as it should. Although, this is, of course, caused by my rather silly loop to begin with, so good to know! Thanks for your help :D

Comment: Here's a hint, try entering 'x' as your number to quit. You will find that 'x' quits your loop just as well as 'q'. Try entering 81 as a number, you will also find that mysteriously quits your loop.

Comment: Your bug is actually in your sorting routine which is introducing garbage values into your vector. Try calling `print_vect` before and after you call `sort_vect` and you'll see this happening.

Comment: John : I've done as you mentioned but the content of the vector seems to be the same. Am I misunderstanding you, perchance?

Comment: @user2239017 No I didn;t read your post correctly. I missed the '1' that you entered on the first line. However your sort is bugged, but that's another story.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code skips the second input is because of the way you terminate your first input loop.

Your first loop terminates not because you detect that user has entered 'q', but because 'q' is not a valid integer. Any letter, 'q', 'x', 'z' or anything would stop your loop.

Trying to read an integer from a letter causes an error in `cin`. Once that error has happened `cin` will not read anything more, so it 'skips' the remaining input.

To see that this is the case try changing your code so that you enter -1 to quit, like this

```
cout << "Enter a number into the vector (-1 to quit) > ";

while(cin >> input && input >= 0)
{
    int_vect.push_back(input);
    cout << "> ";
}
```

Now you are no longer causing an error in `cin` because everything is an integer, and your second input will now work.

For a proper fix you need to look at the suggestions I made in the comments. Basically when you are trying to read integers and/or letters, you need to read a string first and convert to an integer later.